# How do I properly include and link the Crypto++ library in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, crypto++

I've looked at several sources for this, but none of them have solved my problem. I've done includes before in the Java version of Eclipse, but I'm having a lot of trouble with the C++ version.

Here's what I have available. I deleted all the entries I made up to this point. I want to properly include Crypto++ so I can use it.

[image]

I'm not sure what entries to make, or where. The Crypto++ 7.0.0 folder is currently on my desktop.

Comment: You're in the right place. Add the search path and then A) Build. B) Use the linker errors to make a list of what you still need. C) Look up the list you made in B in the library documentation to find out what library is required. D) Add the appropriate libraries. Typically you want the raw library name, so remove any "lib" prefixes and file extensions.

Comment: @user4581301 Here is one of the errors: undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'. All the errors appear to be part of the library already. I can see the files within the Crypto++ folder itself.

Comment: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lrsa

Comment: *`cannot find -lrsa`* looks incorrect. It says the library name is `librsa.a`. The Crypto++ library name is usually `libcryptopp.a`. Did you change it? You would specify it with `-lcryptopp` or `-l:libcryptopp.a`. Also see [Linux | Compiling and Linking](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Linux#Compiling_and_Linking) on the Crypto++ wiki.